VMware vmmon & vmnet 17.5.1 and Linux kernel 6.8.0 won't compile
After upgrading to kernel 6.8.0,
VMware's vmmon and vmnet couldn't compile, giving the following error:
   ...
   ...
/tmp/vmware-host-modules-w17.5.1/vmmon-only/common/task.c:548:1: warning: no previous prototype for ‘TaskGetFlatWriteableDataSegment’ [-Wmissing-prototypes]
  548 | TaskGetFlatWriteableDataSegment(void)
      | ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/tmp/vmware-host-modules-w17.5.1/vmmon-only/common/task.o: warning: objtool: .text: unexpected end of section
  CC [M]  /tmp/vmware-host-modules-w17.5.1/vmmon-only/common/vmx86.o
In file included from /tmp/vmware-host-modules-w17.5.1/vmmon-only/common/vmx86.c:52:
./arch/x86/include/asm/timex.h: In function ‘random_get_entropy’:
./arch/x86/include/asm/timex.h:12:24: error: implicit declaration of function ‘random_get_entropy_fallback’; did you mean ‘random_get_entropy’? [-Werror=implicit-function-declaration]
   12 |                 return random_get_entropy_fallback();
      |                        ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
      |                        random_get_entropy
   ...
   ...


Is part of the above post meant to be a solution to the problem? If so, you should post it as an answer.  But please be clearer — I don’t understand what you’re saying.

Mkubecek's plain patch on the community forum for VMware 17.5.1 couldn't compile either. 
On his website at Kernel – 6.8 Released – OK with latest NVIDIA and Patched VMware, there's a link titled modules: fix build with -Wmissing-prototypes to patch VMware 17.5.1, which fixes that compilation error, among others.
Hit the green [ <> Code ] button, download the zip file,
unzip it somewhere on the local disk, e.g., /tmp/;
# unzip vmware-host-modules-workstation-17.5.1.zip
# cd vmware-host-modules-workstation-17.5.1/
# make
# make install
# /etc/init.d/vmware restart
Stopping VMware services:
   VMware Authentication Daemon                                        done
   Virtual machine monitor                                             done
Starting VMware services:
   Virtual machine monitor                                             done
   Virtual machine communication interface                             done
   VM communication interface socket family                            done
   Virtual ethernet                                                    done
   VMware Authentication Daemon                                        done
   Shared Memory Available                                             done

Start VMware:
# vmware


I'm getting an error "'naked' return found in RETHUNK build". Am I the only one to get this?

It's works for me:
git clone https://github.com/mkubecek/vmware-host-modules.git
cd vmware-host-modules
git switch workstation-17.5.1
make
sudo make install

make install - need with sudo to rewrite modules file for kernel -
install: cannot create regular file '/lib/modules/6.8.0-40-generic/misc/vmmon.ko': Permission denied
install: cannot remove '/lib/modules/6.8.0-40-generic/misc/vmnet.ko': Permission denied


I’m not sure what this really adds to lucasart’s answer (other than detail).

check this workaround
https://github.com/torvalds/linux/pull/857
until vmware fixes the include files from asm/timex.h to linux/timex.h in a future release.
to apply it manually
sudo nano /usr/src/kernels/$(uname -r)/arch/x86/include/asm/timex.h

then add this line below the last #include line
unsigned long random_get_entropy_fallback(void);

then run
sudo vmware-modconfig --console --install-all

and it will work just fine

OR

run this script to fix vmware itself
#!/bin/sh

# switch to the vmmware modules source dir
cd /usr/lib/vmware/modules/source/

# create backup of the modules
cp vmmon.tar vmmon.tar.bak

# extract the module with code issue 
tar -xvf vmmon.tar 

# fix the line that caused the build to fail
sed  -i "s/asm\/timex/uapi\/linux\/timex/" vmmon-only/common/vmx86.c 

# package the module again
tar -cvf vmmon.tar vmmon-only

# remove the working dir 
rm -rf vmmon-only

# try to rebuild the module 
vmware-modconfig --console --install-all

the real issue it vmware includes the wrong header file
Cheers

Working great using Fedora 40 with kernel 6.8.9

A little addition to the answer of Amr Osman:
extern unsigned long random_get_entropy_fallback(void);
It is specified in the mentioned pull request: https://github.com/torvalds/linux/pull/857

This answer does not help solve the problem.

Hi, number9. This means you have yet another reason for that error. Please write your solution if you find it.
